# DataFrame on sqlalchemy printing numbers instead of the actual columns name

Tags: python, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I am working on sqlalchemy, when I run the code below to get a table from a database, however, instead of the actual column name, it displays 1,2,3,4... could someone please help me out?

```html
table = session.execute('select * from station s inner join measurement m on s.station = m.station').fetchall()
data_df = pd.DataFrame(table)
data_df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should be reading in dataframes from SQL using SQLAlchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd                                                        

engine = create_engine('your connection string here')        
df = pd.read_sql('your query here',con=engine)
```